# From local development to dockerized microservices

Tags: networking, docker, microservices, service-discovery

I am getting started with dockerized micro services.

A couple of them are running (see the code snippet below). In my local test setup, each service was available at `localhost:somePort`. E.g. the frontend would try to connect to the backend API at `localhost:backend1`.
Now in the containerized world this does not work anymore. Am I supposed to run a full fledged service discovery solution like `consul` or `etcd`? Or should I just try to access the backend from the frontend using docker's naming service? https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

```
version: '2'
services:
  service1-backend:
    image: service1:0.0.1
    links:
      - service1-frontend
  service1-frontend:
      image: service1-frontend:0.0.1
      links:
            - service2-frontend
      ports:
              - "8080:80"
  service2-backend:
      image: service2-backend:0.0.1
      links:
            - service1-backend
            - service2-frontend
            - service3
  service2-frontend:
      image: service2-frontend:0.0.1
      ports:
              - "8081:80"
  service3:
      image: service3:0.0.1
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't have too many services?

Comment: Well for this question only `service1-backend` and `service1-frontend` are relevant. But there will be more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `service1-frontend` needs to access `service1-backend` via `name:port`, you need:

1. `service1-backend` needs to have a port expose specified in its Dockerfile
2. `service1-frontend` needs to have a link to `service1-backend` in the compose file.

Then in the frontend, you can access backend simply use `service1-backend:port`.

Comment: This is not enough when using multiple instances of same service though (unless you want to have additional service for load-balancing - this is not recommended though). Then services need to communicate via their unique ip (172.x.x.x). For a simplest use case it's fine. You can also use unique environment variable provided for docker for each container - HOSTNAME.